# How do I see the errors shown in the Google Developers Console Project Page?

Tags: google-cloud-console

I'm on the Google Developers Console Project page (https://console.developers.google.com/project) and I can see that I have a number of errors for one of the Projects.

It says that the number displayed is the number that Google has sent over the past 24 hours.

Where are these errors displayed? Were they sent to my email? I'm not sure where to view them so that I can resolve them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the project and go to the [Monitoring -> Logs](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/logs) section in order to access the [Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer) which retrieves data from the [Google Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/) service

Depending on whether you use Google App Engine or Google Compute Engine, if you do not see any logs, then see [Getting Started](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/getting-started) for instructions on what to do to setup the logging for your project.

Comment: Thanks for that but 'Google Cloud Messaging for Android' is the only Google API that I am using. I am accessing it through a RoR server.

Comment: In that case you can't see any logs. Because there is no code of your own to see logs for. I don't know why you need logs then, as the errors "displayed" messages you mentioned are unrelated to Google Cloud Messaging. Please follow the [Try Cloud Messaging for Android guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) and  [Implementing GCM Client on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client). More specifically, follow the get a configuration file wizard from [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config)

Comment: Clicking on the question mark next to the word 'Errors' on the projects page indicates the Errors relate to 'All App Engine traffic and all API usage'. That clearly states API usage. That is why I am trying to find where I can get more information about the errors. I understand this may not be normal but there are a lot of people using on the APIs and not the App Engine as well.

Comment: Can you update your answer with a screenshot or a precise rendering of the message you are seeing?

Comment: Note that this has changed as of the new UX redesign. The new way to access this is Hamburger menu > Logging.